# MySQL, min date query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which stores the exam results of all students in a class. Each record has the following 3 fields: student_id, grade and date (unix time format). Taking into consideration that not all students take all exams and that some students have joined the school after the beginning of the year, what is the easiest query to get the date, grade and student_id of the earliest exam for each student?

Here is the final answer based on Raheel Shan's answer (I don't like ot answer my own question)

```
SELECT m.*  
FROM class AS m  
INNER JOIN (  
  SELECT student_id, MIN(date) AS date  
  FROM class  
  GROUP BY student_id) as l  
ON l.date = m.date 
AND l.student_id = m.student_id
```

Comment: Please show us the query that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the MIN date records

```
select
  m.*
from mytable as m
  inner join (select
        id,
        min(id)
          from mytable
          group by id) as l
    on l.id = m.id
```